# If an anchor tag is stored in Redis, does it cut off the closing anchor tag upon retrieval?

Tags: c#, redis

This seems to me like it would certainly be no, but I'm storing three links in three keys of a Redis hash. In Redis, the data is stored as `< a href ="exampleurl.com">title</a>` but when I retrieve the links into my C# project, it returns to the page as `< a href ="exampleurl.com">title`
(no closing tag.)

Is it safe to say that Redis doesn't randomly cut off the closing anchor tag from a given key or do I need to do something with the returned data to have it present to the user as a hyperlink?

Edit - I'm using the StackExchange.Redis namespace and to get/set the hash I'm using HashSet and HashGet on my Redis database instance. When viewing in a Redis GUI, the hyperlinks are all there, properly formatted. I'm setting an asp Literal and in the code behind doing

```
Link1 = cache.HashGet(finalUrl, "sidebar:link1");
this.uxLink1.Text = Link1;
```

uxLink1 is in the front-end, displayed to the user.
It's odd, I can append a random string like + "hello" to the Link1 variable but not `</a>` like how StackOverflow doesn't let you just write out the closing anchor bracket without making it a code sample.

Comment: That seems to be a data serialization/deserialization issue. Could you provide more details about how are you storing/retrieving the key value?

Comment: @usuario Just updated to show how the info is being stored/retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag stored in Redis has a space in between the opening bracket and the a like so "< a" This was the problem. When I take out the space between the two characters, the links load up without a problem. Never would have guessed that!